# Can a Unix (Linux) System Launch a GUI from CLI Like (Apple/Microsoft) DOS?

Tags: linux, terminal, graphics

My first encounters with a CLI (and computers generally), involved booting to a command prompt, usually inserting a disc, and loading a full screen GUI program that was not windowed in what we commonly see today as GUI based OS.

It went something like this.  Boot >> Prompt>> [Load Rocky's Boots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocky%27s_Boots) >>
Launch Rocky's Boots >> Quit >> Prompt

I've never seen that happen with a Unix / Linux based system, loading directly to a graphical program not in a windowed OS environment - only ascii based programs like Space Invaders, or VIM.  Does the ability exist to do the aforementioned DOS-like loading of 8-bit graphical programs (I stress, not windowed in OSX or Unity or whatever)? If not, why is it different?

Comment: If you down-vote please say why... I just joined for pete's sake

Comment: Of course that is possible, one example of it is X (but I have seen others). X is started from a CLI (or automatically from configuration). The usual command is startx (or used to be, I haven't started a GUI like that in some time).

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to say way you down vote on this site, that is well documented. Please don't whine about it.

Comment: Well, that helps. I'm here to learn. Is X the same as X-Windows?

Comment: @Zach, yes, X is the same as X Window.

Comment: @Anthon where's that documentation?

Comment: @Anthon and honestly it was a light-hearted question of general Unix curiosity on a Sunday morning...   next time I'll move it to Reddit so everybody doing serious things can get back to work

Comment: @Zach_is_my_name First of all it is documented by the behaviour of the system. If the makers of [se] would want you to give commentary, or be non-anonymous, that would be built into the web-site (just like you cannot post a question without a title). Then there is [this](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/791/), [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32226), [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66020), with links of their own to questions, answers and reasons. Hovering above the downvote arrow IMO says it all: too little research, not useful, unclear.

Comment: @Anthon " If the makers of Stack Exchange would want you to give commentary, or be non-anonymous, that would be built into the web-site (just like you cannot post a question without a title" I don't understand.  The site does offer a mechanism for giving commentary on a vote.  As we are doing right now.  I'm not frustrated that people are downvoting (that is their right).  I'm frustrated that I don't have any specific information on why they are downvoting, so that I can place a better question next time

Comment: @Zach_is_my_name The system doesn't have a mechanism to comment on a vote. It has a comment system, that is completely unrelated to the voting system. The only thing they have in common is that they are both enabled by a certain level of reputation. (And although all people being able to downvote are able to comment (125 vs 50 reputation), they are not forced by the system to do so). My guess is that people who downvoted didn't think you researched well enough, but there is no way to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is hard to understand entirely, but I take it you’re asking if it’s possible, in Linux, to start a graphical program from a text-mode console, without the typical (X- or Wayland-based) GUI.

The answer to that is yes, and it always has been (on Linux at least). The mechanisms to do this have changed over the years. Currently, programs which support this type of feature usually do so using the framebuffer, aka `fbdev`, often using a library called `libdirectfb`. Examples include VLC and mplayer, so you can play videos without running an X or Wayland server. X and Wayland are also examples, and they also support `fbdev`, but they usually use other mechanisms (KMS with DRM, or specific drivers).

In the past, many games supported this using a library called SVGAlib, but that has not been supported for a long time. Examples of this include Doom, Quake, Abuse...

Comment: Ai, my systems knowledge is not good enough to write a perfect question.  I'm referring to what must be common experience in DOS systems of loading straight to 8-bit graphical screen from a command, and if there is an equivilent in Linux Unix

Comment: I will follow up the leads you offered Stephen, thanks

Comment: There were similar possibilities on other platforms. In Xenix, I exploited that as early as 1985 (on a PDP-11 system) and in SunOS (Sparc-1)  from 1990. It might involve some trial and error as for determining the order of B/W pixels in a word, or later the RGB(A) channel layout (this was before the Internet would give you a way to find most of that information), but it was, in my experience, always relatively easy to do.

Comment: @StephenKitt - sorry for duplicating part of your answer, I started typing when no answer was posted and ended up getting coffee and taking the dog out

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there are programs that have (historically) worked like that on *nix systems.

The two good examples I can think of off the top of my head are the original classic quake (20+ years old and still fraggin'!), and of course the X windows system.

The first is fairly obvious - it worked that way on DOS systems, and with *nix you could do software rendering and use a SVGALIB binary and you could launch from a pure command line system into the game, just as you describe in your question.  No X windows required.

But what's this I said about the X windows system?  You have to remember that X is NOT part of the operating system, it is a (mostly) user-land application in and of itself.  If you start an X server and don't tell it to query a login server (ie, a remote box via XDMCP or the local machine even) to start/display a display manager/login/greeter, you get just a gray hashmarked screen with your cursor.  It is even possible to configure a graphical application to use that root level window (the very very first "window") as its display, and without a window manager running you won't get close/minimize/maximize buttons, possibly not scroll bars, no title bar to grab and drag, etc.  Kiosk systems, Point Of Sale systems, etc tend to do this.  Not exactly what you reference in your question (Quake though is...) but very similar in behavior.

Comment: If I could vote I would... Helpful!

Comment: To your point about Point of Sale systems, surely there must have been graphical business programs (maybe some games like Quake you mentioned) written for the unix system that either pre-date or were contemporary to Microsoft DOS.  I'm interested in exploring that too... The less "command-ish" side of unix applications...

Comment: @Zach_is_my_name Note that a typical display of the time was not comparable to the CGA displays of the IBM PC. Unix terminals communicated over serial lines, and most provided only text output. Some used escape-sequences to provide some graphical capabilities (see [Waveform Graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waveform_graphics) or the later [ReGIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReGIS) from DEC's VT line)

Comment: @fox Good context and keywords to follow

Comment: fox brings up a good point - do you consider something like ncurses to be graphical?